# Null Pointer Exception when passing value from Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The parent activity has a String List that's instantiated like this.

```
    List<String> taskList = asList("Write some code", "Database stuff", "Test the cloud!");
```

It also has a HeadlineSelected-listener implemented as an interface, along with an ArticleSelected-method. The ArticleSelected-method removes an element from the list.

```
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        taskList.remove(position);
    }
```

In the fragment, I have a HeadlineListener to send stuff to it's parent activity.

```
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;
```

In the fragment, I use the HeadlineListener once an Item is chosen.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
        finish();
}
```

I can start the app just fine, but when I select an item the app stops and I get a Null Pointer Excpetion. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your `onAttach` of Fragment and where you initializ mCallback

Comment: In what line are you getting the NullPointerException? Please post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I select an item the app stops and I get a Null Pointer
>   Excpetion. What am I doing wrong?

You need to initialize `mCallBack`. I am not sure if initialize is the right term.

But you need the below.

Quoting docs

> The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its
>   onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in
>   order to communicate with the Activity.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I got the error was because I'd made the List un-alterable by setting it's values in the cosntructor. If I didn't set the values at all when taskList was created as a member variable.

```
private List<String> taskList;
```

I could then make it into a clean List in the onCreate

```
taskList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add the elements afterwards. Since I was going to scale it up to read from a database in it's onCreate, this wasn't an issue.